# Multiple SimpleFeatureType in ShapefileDataStore or List type in atributes

Tags: java, arcgis, geotools, arcgis-js-api

I have an application which exports an ArcGIS map points. Receipt points in a Spring MVC controller.

My Pointer has a list of attributes that can be variable. The attributes are a list of strings with two values, name and value. Code:

```
public class PointDTO {
    private String type;
    private Double x;
    private Double y;
    private Integer wkid;
    private List<String[]> atributtes = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

He wanted to know if you can use a list type or something similar to this in the SimpleFeatureType:

```
SimpleFeatureType type = DataUtilities.createType ("Location", "the_geom: Point: srid = 25829"
                 + "Type: String"
                 + "X: double," + "And: double,"
                 + "Atributes: List");
```

Right now what I do is to have a 'Attribute' string type. And I concatenate all the attributes but has a maximum length of 250 characters.

Another solution would be to declare several SimpleFeatureType but I think you can not use the same ShapefileDataStore.

Also I have problem importing words with accents in online ArcgisExporer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like the following to create your FeatureTypes and Features for each of your types. Then it's a simple case of generating a ShapefileDatastore to write each set out.

```
package spike;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryBuilder;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

public class ShpFileBuilder {
    static final GeometryBuilder GEOMBUILDER = new GeometryBuilder();

    public SimpleFeatureType buildType(PointDTO dto) {
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName(dto.type);
        builder.setNamespaceURI("http://www.geotools.org/");
        builder.setSRS("EPSG:25829");
        builder.add("the_geom", Point.class);
        for (String[] att : dto.atributtes) {
            builder.add(att[0], String.class);
        }
        SimpleFeatureType featureType = builder.buildFeatureType();
        return featureType;

    }

    public SimpleFeature buildFeature(PointDTO dto, SimpleFeatureType schema) {
        SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(schema);
        Point p = GEOMBUILDER.point(dto.x.doubleValue(), dto.y.doubleValue());
        builder.set("the_geom", p);
        for (String[] att : dto.atributtes) {
            builder.set(att[0], att[1]);
        }
        return builder.buildFeature(dto.wkid.toString());
    }

    public class PointDTO {
        private String type;
        private Double x;
        private Double y;
        private Integer wkid;
        private List<String[]> atributtes = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        // Getters & Setters
    }
}
```